# Weblogic set system property and use in java

Tags: java, weblogic, system-properties

I'm running Weblogic locally, but will run also be run in production on server instances administred from weblogic server

I have set a system property in Weblogic using, "`-DRUNTIME_ENVIRONMENT=LOCALHEST`" under the menu item in Servers -> Configuration-> Server start -> Arguments:

I my java file, i have `System.out.println("ENVR_:" + System.getProperty("RUNTIME_ENVIRONMENT"));`

And it prints null, is there some argument i have missed?

Comment: How are you starting the appserver? As stated in another answer, it needs to be run via Node Manager.

Comment: @Vixen was your issue solved ? Just curious here was the problem because of the Node Manager, or because you didn't select the variable JAVA_OPTIONS when you set your System Property value to -DRUNTIME_ENVIRONMENT=LOCALHEST ? ( probably a typo here you meant localhost but is irrelevant to the question itself )  cheers !

Comment: @Edi not yet havn't checked node manager yet, will do when i am back at work

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't use these configurations when running locally on only one adminserver? And also typo is correct, didn't want to search for localhost in the logs, easier to find if not same as something else. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have to add "set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -Druntime.environment=local" to the startWebLogic.cmd file

Answer (score 3):

I believe the settings on that page apply only if Node Manager is used. So you will need to start your application server with Node Manager and not using the command line or other means.

Answer (score 0):

> If you are using Linux/Mac OS(I am using WebLogic 12.2 on Mac):

- Find the file startWebLogic.sh then edit
- Find and this line change this line `JAVA_OPTIONS="${SAVE_JAVA_OPTIONS} -Denv=dev"`
- -Denv=dev is the environment you want